# Algorithm to assign elements of Var1 to elements of Var2 randomly in R

Tags: r, algorithm, function, matching

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

presenter<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
reviewers<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")

b<-CJ(presenter,reviewers)
data<-data.frame(b)

       V1   V2
 1      A    A
 2      A    B
 3      A    C
 4      A    D
 5      A    E
 6      A    F
 7      A    G
 8      B    A
 9      B    B
```

In other words, is there a way to automate the process so the output would be randomized and not ordered like above? Alternatively, is there a way to assign random values inside `data[nrow,ncol]`?

Comment: expect length of p and q?

Comment: not sure I understand your question, Steve.

Comment: Something like `replicate(10, p[p %in% sample(q, 2, TRUE)])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the size of the input

if input is small then
do a full cross join for the two sets, and pick 10 out of the result

If input is not small then you do the following
(I will use your sample as example)

```
int rand;
Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary...
for(int I = 0; I<10; I++)
{
    rand = random(0, c.length)
    dict [rand]++;
}
Dictionary<int, List<string>> result = new Dictionary...
foreach (int key in dict.Keys)
{
    tempCopy = c.copy();
    for(int I = 0; I < dict[key]; I++)
    {
        rand = random(0, tempCopy.length);
        result[key].Add(tempCopy[rand]);
        tempCopy.removeAt(rand);
    }
}
```

Result dictionary's key would be the corresponding index of c which would be p's letter, and the value of result dictionary would be a list of characters which are from q. cross join those two and you will have the final result

In case you don't know what a cross join is, [1, 2] cross join [3, 4, 5] => 13 14 15 23 24 25

Comment: Steve, many thanks for the tip. I cross joined p and q and got an output with 49 rows. However, I was wondering if there was any way to randomize or shuffle the elements so that the final output wouldn't look like my updated code above?                                                                 A A

Comment: @user3339295 to shuffle you just make a shuffle function....very easy to shuffule an array tbh

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `expand.grid`:

```
p <- c("A", "B")
q <- c("A", "B")

expand.grid(p, q)[sample(length(p) * length(q)), ]
#   Var1 Var2
# 2    B    A
# 4    B    B
# 1    A    A
# 3    A    B
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
 CJ(presenter, reviewers)[,.SD[sample(.N)]]
```

Or as @Arun suggested (in `1.9.3+ data.table` version)

```
 CJ(presenter, reviewers)[sample(.N)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> p = q = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
> ddf = data.frame(
       pp=paste0('p',p), 
       pq1=paste0('q',sample(q,length(p),TRUE)),
       pq2=paste0('q',sample(q,length(p),TRUE)) )
> 
> ddf
  pp pq1 pq2
1 pA  qB  qE
2 pB  qA  qB
3 pC  qC  qF
4 pD  qE  qD
5 pE  qE  qC
6 pF  qA  qD
7 pG  qD  qF
```